# displaying two carousels on one page jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, carousel

I have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/4wEbj/2/

I want to be able to have two instances of the carousel on the same page.

How can I modify my JS? I am just not an expert in JS. I tried several things, firstly:

```
function runCarousel(id){

}
```

Also I have used one global counter, How can I localize it to go through all the images?

Creating my runCarousel script to take parameter like this http://jsfiddle.net/4wEbj/3/

But its not loading well. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a for carousel like this:

```
var Carousel = {
imgCounter : 0,
delay : 5000,
id : '',
runCarousel : function (){
    var that = this;
    var done = 0;
    if(that.id!=undefined && that.id!=''){
        var img_len = $('#'+that.id+" .jcarousel ul li img").length;

        $('#'+that.id+" .jcarousel ul li img").each(function(){
            if($(this).css('display')=='block' && done==0){
                that.imgCounter++;
                if(that.imgCounter == img_len){
                   $(this).css('display','none');
                    that.imgCounter = 0;
                    $('#'+that.id+" .jcarousel ul li img").css('display','none');
                    $('#'+that.id+" .jcarousel ul li").find('img:eq(0)').css('display','block');
                } else {
                    $(this).css('display','none');
              $(this).parent().next().find('img').css('display','block');
                }
                done = 1;
            }
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.runCarousel();
        }, that.delay);
    }
  }
}
```

and instantiating like this:

```
var carousel1 = Object.create(Carousel);
carousel1.id = "showSlider1";
carousel1.delay = 5000;
carousel1.runCarousel();
var carousel2 = Object.create(Carousel);
carousel2.id = "showSlider2";
carousel2.delay = 5000;
carousel2.runCarousel();
```

would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get two instances you'll need two carousel divs on the page. In this fiddle I've just copied your carousel-wrapper div and pasted it below the first one. I'm looking into the second one you provided but it looks like the fiddle below does what you want.

two carousels: http://jsfiddle.net/4wEbj/4/

i copied the following div and pasted it:

```
<div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
```

Comment: But then it displays a blank canvas. I don't want that.

Comment: I want it to be able to cycle through all images on both carousel and it should not be having a blank carousel on both the carousel at any time

Comment: the key is img_counter to get it right.. However, I am unable to modify the code to make it so.. Right now, img_counter is global and that's why it cannot work for both the carousel the way I want it..

Comment: I had it working with two separate launches of the carousel function, but couldn't get it working by passing the image ID. I'll try again today when I have some free time.

Comment: I have resolved it already. Thanks a lot. Will post my solution soon.

Comment: @David Briand Please find my solution below.